# Unable to pass value from component to template

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, components

I've defined a variable, `MIN_PW`, above my component's `export class MyComponent`, and although the intellisense recognizes it in my `formBuilder` it's not appearing in the UI properly (UI shows "Password must contain at least characters").

Originally I'd defined the variable within `export class` and it *was* working, but I was advised to set it with `const` and move it above the component.

**Component file:**

```
const MIN_PW = 12;

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(MIN_PW)]),
      // etc
  )

}
```

**Template file:**

```
<mat-form-field class="password-field">
<mat-error *ngIf="myFormGroup.controls['password'].invalid">Password must contain at least {{MIN_PW}} characters.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to declare all of your constants in a separated file, which you will import wherever you want.

To me, the following approach seems more straight forward for your case:

1. Define and export your constants in one or multiple TS files.
2. Import the constants using import { MY_CONSTANT } from '../constants/my-constant.ts'; where ever you need them.
3. Use them and be happy.